# Where to find ransomware samples to make demonstrations?

Tags: ransomware

I'm looking for some ransomware samples that work on Linux so that I can show a proof of concept with Qubes OS on how one's other virtual machines can be safe from a ransom attack if a single virtual machine (or a disposable virtual machine) gets compromised.

But I don't know where I can find such samples. Can anyone help?

Comment: @Rice  I don't *want* malware, I want a ransomware **sample** ***for educational purposes only*** (ideally it should just encrypt the files and show a fake ransom note and not be a perfect crystal copy of an existing ransomware)

Comment: I found two, hidden tears and bash-ransomware. Just search for open source ransomware and your bound to find something. That being said, if you just want something to encrypt some files and leave a ransom note, it wouldn't be too tough to find some sort of encryption program on github and modify it for your needs. This would be a safer alternative as well.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you don't need ransomware to demonstrate what happens.  You could fake the output of the attack using openssl like this:

Encrypt:  `openssl aes-256-cbc -pass pass:pwd -in victim -out victim.ransom && rm victim`

Decrypt:  `openssl aes-256-cbc -pass pass:pwd -d -in victim.ransom -out victim`

However, it looks like you may be more interested in demonstrating the activity of the ransomware file system scanner, to prove that your isolated VM can't encrypt the files of the host system or of other guest systems.  That's rather like proving a negative.  The best demonstration might be to show how find works, because that's exactly what ransomware would have to do.

Create a file named `/tmp/sacrificial_pic_<vmname>.jpg` on each of the VMs, including the VM hosting the fake malware, substituting the machine name in the filename above.   Run the find command on the VM hosting the fake malware, like this:

```
find / -name \*.jpg -print
```

This will emulate the activity of malware searching for picture files to encrypt.  The only sacrificial JPG your find command should discover is the one on your local VM.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to demonstrate the risk of ransomware is to write a simple shell script that encrypts files in a folder. Not only will this prove useful, but it is also *very easy to understand* for people who are not technically literate or inclined.

Linux has `openssl` as an optional package where as most Windows systems has `cipher` built in.

A relevant discussion around proper backup policies should also be included.

Answer (score 2):

Why not make a quick one ?

As a demo, you only need:

- an archiver with command line like 7zip,
- a target file (document) to encrypt
- a nice picture asking for ransom
- a batch/script file to make an archive

You make the batch/script file of the document with password and then within the same script file you erase the document. You will have no original document and an encrypted file (and for password you need to pay the ransom). As proof of concept it's quite enough to demonstrate what you want.

Comment: The OP asked for Linux versions. You appear to be suggesting Windows-centric solutions.

Comment: 7zip exists for linux and scripts you can do just the same. There is no relevance on what operating system you do it. The proof of concept will behave in a very similar manner.

Comment: Sure, but the other answers appear to be saying the same thing as you are, and the only difference is that you use Windows terminology. It just makes this answer a little strange.

Answer (score 1):

Most of malware can be identified by hash (MD5, SHA1, etc.). You may need to find the hash and search (which will bring you to the site provides samples you want) or random look up on [this list](https://github.com/rshipp/awesome-malware-analysis#malware-corpora).